# Getting "Invalid request provided: Only global scoped ARNs are supported" when creating a CloudFront distribution for a regional ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an AWS CDK stack that defines a WAFv2 ACL and then a CloudFront distribution that associates the ACL with it. What I want to do is create a regionally scoped ACL so that I don't have to create it in the us-east-1 region (I found this requirement in the [CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_wafv2/CfnWebACL.html)).

Here's the relevant CDK code:

```
    cloudfront_acl = wafv2.CfnWebACL(self, "ACL",
                                     scope="REGIONAL",
                                     default_action=wafv2.CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty(block={}),
                                     visibility_config=wafv2.CfnWebACL.VisibilityConfigProperty(
                                         cloud_watch_metrics_enabled=True,
                                         metric_name="WAF",
                                         sampled_requests_enabled=True,
                                     ),
                                     rules=[
                                         wafv2.CfnWebACL.RuleProperty(
                                             name="ip-list",
                                             priority=1,
                                             action=wafv2.CfnWebACL.RuleActionProperty(allow={}),
                                             statement=wafv2.CfnWebACL.StatementProperty(
                                                 ip_set_reference_statement=ip_ref_statement
                                             ),
                                             visibility_config=wafv2.CfnWebACL.VisibilityConfigProperty(
                                                 sampled_requests_enabled=True,
                                                 cloud_watch_metrics_enabled=True,
                                                 metric_name="allow-permitted-ips",
                                             )
                                         )
                                     ]
                                     )

    cf_dist = cloudfront.Distribution(self, 'UICloudFrontDist',
                                      default_behavior=cloudfront.BehaviorOptions(
                                          origin=origins.S3Origin(ui_bucket)),
                                      default_root_object="index.html",
                                      web_acl_id=cloudfront_acl.attr_arn
                                      )
```

When I try to deploy this stack with the CDK, I get an error message like this one:

```
"Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Only global scoped ARNs are supported arn:aws:wafv2:{region}:{account}:regional/webacl/ACL (Service:CloudFront, Status Code: 400, Request ID: b9e6f291-1272-4c71-b6a1-eba717d42689)" (RequestToken: b2d576dd-3b28-4ab5-3473-bd49f07c0519, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)"
```

I can't find any information on this error message. Can someone explain what the root cause of this problem is?

Comment: I believe that the scope value of `"REGIONAL"`  is not correct that it instead should be something like `aws_wafv2. CfnWebACL.REGIONAL` - most of these kinds of values are covered by Enums in CDK, and so if you pass a String it will either fail or default to whatever (in this case perhaps global).  -- but having not directly worked with this before, I do not know where the enum would be.

Answer (score 2):

AWS CDK documentation says:

> "Specifies whether this is for an Amazon CloudFront distribution or for a regional application. A regional application can be an Application Load Balancer (ALB), an Amazon API Gateway REST API, an AWS AppSync GraphQL API, an Amazon Cognito user pool, an AWS App Runner service, or an AWS Verified Access instance. Valid Values are CLOUDFRONT and REGIONAL."

**=> you should write "CLOUDFRONT" if you use your WAF for cloudfront, and "REGIONAL" for other kind of resources.**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-ipset.html#cfn-wafv2-ipset-scope